# Redundancy in doing sum()

Tags: sql, oracle10g

table1 -> id, time_stamp, value

This table consists of 10 id's. Each id would be having a value for each hour in a day. 
So for 1 day, there would be 240 records in this table.

table2 -> id

Table2 consists of a dynamically changing subset of id's present in table1.

At a particular instance, the intention is to get sum(value) from table1, considering id's only in table2, 
grouping by each hour in that day, giving the summarized values a rank and repeating this each day.

the query is at this stage:

```
select time_stamp, sum(value),
rank() over (partition by trunc(time_stamp) order by sum(value) desc) rn
from table1
where exists (select t2.id from table2 t2 where id=t2.id)
and
time_stamp >= to_date('05/04/2010 00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24') and
time_stamp <= to_date('25/04/2010 23','dd/mm/yyyy hh24')
group by time_stamp
order by time_stamp asc
```

If the query is correct, can this be made more efficient, considering that, table1 will actually consist of thousand's of id's instead of 10 ?

EDIT: I am using sum(value) 2 times in the query, which I am not able to get a workaround such that the sum() is done only once. Pls help on this

Comment: The main cost of doing a SUM is not the actual adding-the-numbers-together bit; the main cost is the retrieving of the data from the source tables. So feel free to put as many SUMs throughout the select clause as you like :)

Comment: Thanks. But, won't it hamper the time consumption even in a slightest way? Because for some data sets, the query is taking more than 10 seconds to complete. So, any little efficient workaround would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>from table1
    where exists (select t2.id from table2 t2 where value=t2.value)</strike>

The table2 doesn't have `Value` field. Why is the above query with `t2.Value`?

You could use a join here

```
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on  t1.id = t2.id
```

EDIT: Its been a while that I worked on Oracle. Pardon me, if my comment on `t2.Value` doesn't make sense.

Comment: No problem. Using `join` or 'inner join` could be of help in your case.